# Is necessary to use salt if I use a complex password?

Tags: passwords, salt

I read that it is important to use a salt together with the password to avoid rainbow table attack. I agree with that, but is there any difference, in terms of security, if

- I use password + salt or
- I use a complex password?

That is, do I need a salt to avoid rainbow table attacks if I use a complex password?

Comment: To clarify, salting is something that the server should do to passwords: it isn't something that you should do to *your* passwords.  If you are talking about choosing your own password to use when you register with a website, then you don't have to worry about salting at all - just choose a strong, unique password.  If you are building a website and are creating a login system then you need to add salts to all passwords because your users probably won't use a complex password, leaving your hashes vulnerable to rainbow attacks if your database leaks.

Comment: Besides avoiding rainbow tables and brute-forcing attacks, I'd like to note that not everyone uses complex passwords. Even if *your* password is complex enough to avoid being cracked, someone else's password is probably something like `password123`, in which case we still need those measures.

Comment: As written, the question is confusing. Are you talking about hashing or managing your personal passwords? How is having a complex password relevant to salting?

Comment: @shroeder looking at another question by the user on the same day, the user is asking for backend storage.
I believe the main question is coming up as "Does the backend need to salt passwords if they're XX+ random chars?". I do agree though that the user needs to describe the question better.

Answer (score 2):

The salt is what is going to add flavor to each password and make each hash unique. It's not related to how complex your password is.

If I get your password hash file and you have no salt, the process to generate all those hashes was the same and I have only one unknown key to guess. So I can use the pre-compiled (rainbow) table to find a match and know it.

But by adding a salt to each password, each line would become unique. You are adding an extra layer of security and those two users with the password "Password" won't have the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing using salt and password strength is like wondering where the security of your bank can protect your home door. Salt is a server level thing, related to the way the server stores the hashes of (all) its clients'password. Password strength is related to an individual password and can be seen as the number of different passwords built on same scheme.

If you are building a server system, salting greatly improves the security of the password database. If you want to choose a strong password for a site, try to imagine the number of similar passwords (4 decimal digit is only 10000, very weak - 12 random characters from the base64 set is 64^12 much stronger).

As they occur at different levels, both should be used.